# using ExoPlayer with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I want to use ExoPlayer using kotlin, I saw code for that but my compiler can't recognize 'buildRenderersFactory' reference.
Can someone help?
I'm using android studio
and implement:
def exoPlayerVersion = "2.9.0"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:$exoPlayerVersion"

```
private val defaultBandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(context).build()

private val dataSourceFactory: DefaultDataSourceFactory

private val extractorsFactory = DefaultExtractorsFactory()   

private val renderersFactory = buildRenderersFactory(useExtensionRenderers = true, preferExtensionRenderer = true)

val exoPlayer :SimpleExoPlayer =  ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, renderersFactory,  DefaultTrackSelector(), DefaultLoadControl())

val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(context, defaultBandwidthMeter, DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(Util.getUserAgent(context, "MKDPlayer"),  defaultBandwidthMeter))

val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory,extractorsFactory)
    .setCustomCacheKey("ExoPlayerAdapter")
    .createMediaSource(uri)
    
exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource)
```

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5573-media-playback-on-android-with-exoplayer-getting-started

Comment: Hey, thanks, I found a code there that helped me solve the problem. He used constructor of DefaultRenderersFactory class.

Answer (score 0):

As Usama Altaf send me a link. The solution is using DefaultRenderersFactory constuctor.
so now it looks that way:

val renderersFactory = DefaultRenderersFactory(context)